# How to test correlation of two variables from four repeated measures of each one among four groups

Tags: correlation, repeated-measures, small-sample

I have **four plots** from where I took a measure of two indicators of population abundance (as continuous variables) throughout **four surveys** (say, at spring 2010, fall 2010, spring 2011, fall 2011).
So, data are like this:
`Plot    Time    Var1    Var2
1   1   0.96    0.48
1   2   0.56    0.11
1   3   2.14    0.48
1   4   0.07    0.14
2   1   6.37    0.86
2   2   2.67    0.70
2   3   2.73    0.64
2   4   2.10    0.63
3   1   2.09    0.98
3   2   0.41    0.27
3   3   1.73    0.80
3   4   0.12    0.18
4   1   6.41    1.20
4   2   1.87    0.39
4   3   4.54    0.88
4   4   1.50    0.60`

In such a (bad) situation, what you would do to get a measure of *strength of association between Var1 and Var2* and test it against null hypothesis of zero correlation?
Thank you so much for any help you may provide.